# how to count items on laravel query?

Tags: php, laravel

i need to count hours. this is my laravel eloquent:

```
$items = Item::ofType('type')->where('start_at','>=',Carbon::today())->groupBy(\DB::raw('HOUR(start_at)'))->count();
```

And this is show me results like 2/2/1

sql query of this:

```
SELECT
    count(*)AS AGGREGATE
FROM
    `items`
WHERE
    `type` = 'type'
AND `start_at` >= '2015-10-15 00:00:00'
GROUP BY
    HOUR(start_at)
```

And how to count 2/2/1 of this and get result = 3?

I need laravel eloquent without RAW.

EDIT:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT
    count(*) AS AGGREGATE
FROM
    `items`
WHERE
    `type` = 'type'
AND `start_at` >= '2015-10-15 00:00:00'
GROUP BY
    HOUR(start_at)) as count
```

how to write this in laravel eloquent?

Comment: Your question seems to be unclear to me. What is `2/2/1` representing? A date?

Comment: it rows count of group by hours. for ex. 2 items in 13h, 2 items in 17h and 1 in 20h. And i need count how many hours are. Of these result is 3

Comment: The code you edited could by accomplished in laravel eloquent by `$count = DB::raw($q)->count()` where `$q` is your attempt above. I do not think you can do this without `DB::raw()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code check laravel documentation on this link. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries

Order By, Group By, And Having

```
$users = DB::table('items')
                    ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
                    ->groupBy('count')
                    ->having('count', '>', 100)
                    ->get();
```